# Setting inputs to a string variable in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

I'm working on setting a character's name to an input the user gives and have got this code:

```
characterOneName = str(input("What is the name of the first character? "))
print(characterOneName)
```

If I try running it with an input of x, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Peter/Documents/ARCHIVES/2. School Work/Current Year/Computing/notepad.py", line 1, in <module>
    characterOneName = str(input("What is the name of the first character? "))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are using Python 2.x only.

Comment: 2.7.3 my bad
how would I get it to work on 2.x?

Comment: Use `raw_input(...)` instead of `str(input(...))`.

Comment: aha thank you!
works now :)

Comment: I have made my comment as an answer, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Use `raw_input` instead of `input` (i.e., use `str(raw_input(...))`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Python 2, not Python 3.